# Python Code Shortening

Tags: python, code-snippets, code-golf

I was trying to solve this problem here :- https://www.spoj.pl/problems/PHIVAL/

The questions asks you to output as many decimal digits of the golden ratio (1+sqrt(5))/2 as possible and also try to minimise the code length.

This is what I have right now. Can this code be made any shorter ?

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec=7050
print(1+Decimal(5).sqrt())/2
```

Comment: the fastest way to do it would be to have a webpage that spits out 1 million digits of phi and have your program just be `echo curl mysite.com\phi` :-)

Comment: Why set precision to 7050? Why not 9999? Just as short code-wise, but many more digits.

Comment: @delnan It would exceed the timelimit.

Comment: @glowcoder .. very clever :) .. But that wouldn't work on the spoj.

Comment: For reference, codegolf.stackexchange.com has a whole bunch of these spoj.pl problems on them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take out the space before the asterisk.

**Update:**

You added the part about insignificant whitespace, so I started thinking about a different approach.  If whitespace isn't counted, you may be able to do something like this

```
print"1."+`map(len,"""      








       """.split("\n"))`[1::3]
```

It encodes each digit as a number of spaces on a line in a multi-line string constant. Obviously, you could add more lines to get more digits.  It should run pretty fast, as there is very little calculation done.  It uses <strike>50</strike> (update 2: 45) non-whitespace characters to produce any number of digits output.

Comment: Thanks. But the source length is counted as the number of non-white space characters.

Comment: @jack_carver: With the new information about white space, I came up with another approach that may give better results.

Comment: You can make any python code to just 44 characters (or 42 in python2) if white space is not counted http://pastebin.com/uHR9TwQT

Answer (score 1):

Taking `recursive`'s approach to an extreme, this uses just 19 non-whitespace characters:

```
print '1.%d'%len('                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ')
```

Granted, the code required to generate the first 1000000 digits would be over 10^1000000 characters in length!

Answer (score 0):

Due to high score for short code, i think that best approach could be just

```
print 1
```

Comment: `score(ndigits=1, codelen=6) -> 2500001`, `score(7050, 68) -> 227638` There must be "at least 1000 [digits] after the decimal point."

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried javascript-ish approach, and it apparently doesn't work in Python:

```
import decimal
decimal.__dict__.values()[17]().prec = 7050
...
```

Looks like your code is pretty close to the shortest possible solution.

Comment: Yes. But due to the varied nature of the formula I cannot exactly figure out the minimal source length. The best python solution there has a score of "307962" Where as mine gives "212528".